# Unable to access the properties of one QML in another

Tags: qt, qml

I have one QML file

**QMLFile1.qml**

```
Rectangle{   

    id: LogicFile
    property int  characters
    property bool checked

}
```

In second QML file **QMLFile2.qml**

If I try and instantiate the first file in a second file like this

```
Rectangle{

   QMLFile1{

         // unable to access the 
         //properties here id: LogicFile
         // property int  characters
         //property bool checked
   }

}
```

Why I am unable to access the properties of first QMLFile inside the second.

However if I instantiate the firstQML file in the second file directly i.e., not inside any element like rectangle , item etc all the properties are accessible why is it so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the properties in the second file, for that:

1. Expose the id of your parent element using **Property alias** to the outside world.
2. Now redefine the id with the aliased id in the second file
3. Now you can access them using aliased id name and and .(dot) operator

**Example:**

QMLFile1.qml

```
Rectangle{
    id: LogicFile
    property alias rectId:LogicFile // exposing id to outside files
    property int  characters
    property bool checked
}
```

QMLFile2.qml

```
Rectangle{

   QMLFile1{

           id:rectId       

          //Now you can access them like rectId.characters/rectId.checked
          rectId.characters = 10 

   }

}
```

Comment: How come it was not happening before :P

Comment: I too am surprised that this technique is required to achieve the OPs goal @SanyamGoel

Comment: I realize that I am commenting 10 years too late, but (as far as I know) that "exposing id to outside files" is completely unnecessary and has no effect. One can simply set values to properties of QmlFile1, by creating an object in QmlFile2 (and assigning an id to it, say "qmlFile2") and, either directly using names of properties inside the object's scope, or in a function like this `qmlFile2.characters`. This answer should be marked for deletion.